# Writing I-Pod data under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ipod

Is there any good way to write music on I-Pod under Ubuntu? Amarok and Rythimbox can both play it, but I can't write it with any of them. Is there any program for that?

Comment: which ipod model do you have?  last i looked, ipod touch models were not supported at all, but i don't keep up with the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.gtkpod.org
Have never used it, but it's worth a try I suppose.

Comment: I do use it, and it works well.  It meets all my needs, which are admittedly few: music and podcasts.  I've not tried to do more (such as video – my iPod doesn't do that).  I was pleasantly surprised recently to see it even transfers album covers if you name image files appropriately. :)